# Subscribe to Spring Metrics channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-integration

So according to the documents of Spring it will publish metrics on a REST endpoint and a message channel.

The REST endpoint works fine as I get the expected result. However I would like to handle each change in the metrics. So it says it will by default publish messages to a channel called "metricsChannel"

I tried to create the following class which would listen to this channel, but it does not seem to fire. Everything else has been kept default for the Spring Boot application.

```
package services.core;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;

@Service
public class MetricService {
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "metricsChannel")
    public void handleMessage(org.springframework.messaging.Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println("Message [" + message.toString() + "] is received");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that Spring Boot see your `MetricService` class? I mean correct package for the `@ComponentScan`

Comment: Yes, because I tested using JMS messaging from the Main method by sending a message to this exact class (different method which I removed for this example) with the same annotations and that worked. So are you implying that this code should have worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested that and works well:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "metricsChannel")
public MessageHandler metricsHandler() {
    return System.out::println;
}
```

I've done that in our `web-sockets` [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/web-sockets) on the `server` part.
Added this:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
```

to that project Gradle config.

And I see this in console, when I started the `client` app:

```
GenericMessage [payload=Metric [name=gauge.response.time.star-star, value=26.0, timestamp=Tue Apr 14 16:03:53 EEST 2015], headers={metricName=gauge.response.time.star-star, id=08697a97-83c1-5000-f031-65f6797c0cd8, timestamp=1429016633672}]
GenericMessage [payload=Metric [name=counter.status.101.time.star-star, value=1, timestamp=Tue Apr 14 16:03:53 EEST 2015], headers={metricName=counter.status.101.time.star-star, id=8d070cb4-88e8-f5a7-6b83-6b27edf75bfc, timestamp=1429016633674}]
```

But, yes: your code is good as well.

Comment: How to publish SpringBoot Micrometer metrics to a metricsChannel or Stdout?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: my code did actually work, but for me it felt like a gotcha.

Quote from Spring docs:

> If the ‘Spring Messaging’ jar is on your classpath a MessageChannel
>   called metricsChannel is automatically created (unless one already
>   exists). **All metric update events** are additionally published as
>   ‘messages’ on that channel. Additional analysis or actions can be
>   taken by clients subscribing to that channel.

So by "**all metric update events**", I thought that the system metrics (memory usage, cpu load etc.) would fall under these events. Actually they are not, they are just being published whenever your custom counters change or for example the number of requests for a certain endpoint.

Initially I was waiting for a message each second or so after bootup, to no avail. Ultimately started to call the metrics endpoint and suddenly the messages starting popping in the console/channel each time I called it.