# Write out Spring Boot metrics to Stdout or aggregator?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, metrics, microservices

I have a java application written on top of Spring Boot and I can see the metrics being generated through the `/metrics` management API. I would like to filter the metrics that are being generated (based on metric prefix) and print to stdout OR send the selected metrics to a 3rd party aggregator (not the ones referenced [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metric-writers))

I tried the code suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627061/subscribe-to-spring-metrics-channel) but it didn't result in any metrics being written to the stdout. This is what I added to my `Application.java` class:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "metricsChannel")
    public MessageHandler metricsHandler() {
        return System.out::println;
}
```

What is the best way to intercept the metrics on a preconfigured cadence so I can process and write them to stdout or publish them to an aggregator?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind to share a simple sample application to see more context? Maybe there is just something disabled...

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/khoubyari/spring-boot-metrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in the Spring Boot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5517.

We have to declare something like this ourselves as a workaround:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel metricsChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ExportMetricWriter
public MessageChannelMetricWriter messageChannelMetricWriter() {
    return new MessageChannelMetricWriter(metricsChannel());
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "metricsChannel")
public MessageHandler metricsHandler() {
    return System.out::println;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @artem. I think it got further but not quite outputting the message. The error is `2016-03-29 09:27:16.924  WARN 11264 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.b.a.m.export.AbstractMetricExporter  : Could not write to MetricWriter: class org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers` ... I wonder which one is `unknown.channel.name`? Also, where would I inspect to only output metrics with a given prefix? Thanks.

Comment: You should share your application. That isn't clear. Maybe you have a `metricsChannel`, but don't have `metricsHandler` bean for that...

Comment: Thanks. I pushed the latest to the project above. I will follow also up on the `metricsHandler` hint.

Comment: Well, you have to change `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` to just the single `@SpringBootApplication`. Those doesn't mark the class with the `@Component` which is important for the scanning `@ServiceActivator` by Spring Integration.

Comment: Thank you! I also implemented a `MessageHandler` in which I can look at the content of the message and take the next step. I pushed the working version to  https://github.com/khoubyari/spring-boot-metrics